# Passing variables betwen functions in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i pass var selekcija to another function? I need to pass var selekcija to another file (load-epizode.php), but my var is i another function.

```
var selekcija
$(document).ready(function() {
    
   $('#sezona').change(function() {
       selekcija = 1;
       selekcija = $('#sezona').val();
       console.log(selekcija);
    });
    $('#epizds').load("/filmovi2/config/load-epizode.php", {
       NewSelekcija: selekcija
    });
        
});
```

Comment: You can pass it as query string /filmovi2/config/load-epizode.php?NewSelekcija=selekcija

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to load content on every 'change' event ?
Move the load inside the change event's function

```
function onSelekcijaChange() {
    const selekcija = $('#sezona').val();
    console.log(selekcija);

    $('#epizds').load("/filmovi2/config/load-epizode.php", {
            NewSelekcija: selekcija
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

   onSelekcijaChange();
   $('#sezona').change(onSelekcijaChange);

});
```

Not the best and optimal JS code but I didn't want to change a lot
of your code.

Comment: Yes, but i need load-epizode.php to be loaded when page loades and to change when someone change options in dropdown menu.

Comment: I see, updated my answer